# List all "incoming" internal links / references to a TYPO3 element

Tags: typo3

I need to get a list of elements linking to a specific TYPO3 page or element (all IDs oder pages, that link or refer to a this element). I thought this was at the Info module, but I can't find it.

I have spent hours finding this info on the web and even in my oldschool TYPO3 manual book... nothing, but I know that I once had this list.

Thanks a lot in advance! (version is TYPO3 4.6, I am preparing an upgrade right now)

Comment: You mean links from fx tt_content header and any given richtexteditor field of all your installed extensions, and also other linkfields from extensions you could have downloaded from TER, Github or self written?

Comment: well...yes but that isn't that much. I understand, that there are several possible sources.
I remember a list like the usage of files list (the one that shows you in which IDs a certain e.g. image is used)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could search your database manually to find such links. I will start to give you a list where you could search for.

Find tt_content headers which link to a page, element or any url:

```
SELECT * FROM tt_content WHERE header_link NOT LIKE '' AND deleted = 0;
```

In RTE fields, you could manually check.
Go to backend modul 'Configuration', choose '$TCA (Tabel configuration array)' and search for 'RTE'.

Then you schould get all RTE fields, which could have links set to any TYPO3 pages or elements.
Like fx: *tt_content.bodytext.config.wizards.RTE...*

These fields you could search for any links vis MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM tt_content WHERE bodytext LIKE '%<link%' OR bodytext LIKE '%<LINK%' AND deleted = 0;
```

Maybe someone can add more default fields not listed above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have seen the references of a record normaly seen in the list module.
If you hover your mouse over the count you get a list of origins.

That list is not always up to date and the usability of the origins differs from version to version. Sometimes you can use the origins as direct link to edit the origin record.
Maybe you had an extension which enhances the usage.

In gerneral: if records are used with TYPO3 (TCA group fields which build relations to other records with uid-lists, or mm-records) this is also stored as refrence.
As links are also relations they are not always stored as referenes, espeacially if the link is inside a textfield.